# не могу добавить дату в столбец при создании новой записи в базе данных

Tags: c#, sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] private void [image: введите сюда описание изображения]button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
database.openConnection();

```
        var id = textBox1.Text;
        var pokupatel = textBox2.Text;
        var tovar = textBox3.Text;
        var edinici_izmerenia = textBox5.Text;
        var gorod = textBox6.Text;
        var data_postavki = textBox7.Text;

        int kol_vo;

        if (int.TryParse(textBox4.Text, out kol_vo))
        {
            var addQuery = $"insert into test (id, pokupatel, tovar, kol_vo, edinici_izmerenia, gorod, data_postavki) values ('{id}', '{pokupatel}', '{tovar}', '{edinici_izmerenia}', '{gorod}',  '{kol_vo}', '{data_postavki}')";

            var command = new SqlCommand(addQuery, database.GetConnection());
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("Запись успешно создана!", "Успех!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Цена должна иметь числовой формат!", "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);          
        }
        database.closeConnection();


    }
```

Comment: У вас текст ошибки на скрине написан, вам в нем что то не понятно?

Comment: а как его назвать тогда может есть какие то требования?

Comment: исправил свои ошибки из за невнимательности но появилась другая ошибка скрин прикрепил новый

Comment: вообще, если у вас другой вопрос - то задавать его надо отдельно. Одна проблема на вопрос. Что касается вашей новой проблемы, не указывайте идентификатор, когда вставляете новую запись.

Comment: понял сейчас создам другой вопрос потому то если не указываю идентификатор то ошибка та же

Comment: вы уже поменяли этот вопрос ) оставьте как есть. Просто на будущее не меняйте кардинально звдвнные вопросы

Comment: под не указываением идентификатора, я имею ввиду уберите его даже из вашего SQL запроса

Comment: понял буду знать

Comment: также, если пишете запросы руками, чтобы избежать SQL инъекций, используйте [параметризированные запросы](https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/2.9.php)